# text ellipsis in second line

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

How do I get the ellipsis in second line with pure CSS?

here is the CSS am using now

```
.desc p{
     display: table-cell;  
     width:90%;  
     vertical-align: middle;  
     height:30px ;  
     overflow: hidden;  
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not currently support multilines. You need to use JavaScript or jQuery. I recommend the [dotdotdot jQuery plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

Comment: Nice link but I need to do it with pure CSS

Comment: yea, setting a height will do that lol, but ellipsis just looks better.

Comment: I gt the last three dots also at the end by using span content